# How I can set interval between two column with date and time in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, date, dateinterval

I want to set day or hour time interval between 2 columns to get lates actual records, if I dont set this I got outdated information when I filter by day.

TableA: create_date
TableB: last_access_date

SO I did this

```
SELECT  *
FROM acc_zone_person
WHERE create_time::date = last_access_time::date
```

I get daily information no outdated information, but at midnight all information between 23:00 - 00:00
disgarded I want to put interval so that my evening information from 19:00 will be present till 06:00 data.

I used

```
SELECT  *
FROM acc_zone_person
WHERE last_access_time::date >= now() - interval '12 hours'
```

this time when I switch to older dates, I dont get any data, only data within 12 hours

so I need to find a way do something like this

```
SELECT  *
FROM acc_zone_person
WHERE create_date::date >= last_access_time - interval '12 hours'
```

It should take create_date as NOW and get 12 hours interval data of last_access_time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your own statement:  "It should take create_date as NOW ... "

```
SELECT  *
FROM acc_zone_person
WHERE now()::date >= last_access_time - interval '12 hours'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused here.  Why couldn't you just use the last query you posted?  Does it not work?  Do you just need to convert the last_update_time to a date?

Comment: Yes I tried this query, but I get older records also from the previeus day(the range is far more biger that I asked 36 hour).... so result is not actual

Comment: @ShohratPermanov I don't think this is an elegant solution but i think you could perhaps combine the middle two queries with an OR clause.  Would that work as a solution?  ```SELECT  *
FROM acc_zone_person
WHERE (create_time::date = last_access_time::date) or (last_access_time::date >= now() - interval '12 hours') ```